# How to use date variable in curl command

Tags: bash, date, curl

I've been attempting to simply create a `curl` command that uses the output of `echo $(date +'%Y-%d-%m')` in the GET request that it makes. I've browsed the posts here and tried a number of solutions, but none seem to work for me.

Here is the example request:

```
curl -s -XGET 'https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date=2021-11-18
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
curl -s -XGET 'https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date=`echo $(date +'%Y-%d-%m')`'
curl -s -XGET 'https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date='$(date +'%Y-%d-%m')'
DATE=$(date +'%Y-%d-%m') ; curl -s -XGET 'https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date="'"$DATE"'"'
```

Any input as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. The `echo` in `echo $(date ...)` is completely useless. 2. Single quotes prevent expansion. Try `curl -s -XGET "https://.../shifts?start_date=$(date +'%Y-%d-%m')"`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be specifying the date format as `%Y-%d-%m`, whereas the string `2021-11-18` corresponds to `%Y-%m-%d`.

```
curl -qsSf "https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A tangent: since bash v4.2, printf can format timestamps, so we don't even need to call out to `date`:

```sh
printf -v url 'https://www.website.com/api/shifts?start_date=%(%Y-%m-%d)T'
curl -qsSf "$url"
```

Providing no arguments means "current time"